# Swift: able to make a HTTP request via WiFi but not via Cellullar network

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, xcode6

I was following the swift tutorial 
http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/

here's the code I am using to make the http call:

```
func post(params : Dictionary<String, String>, url : String, postCompleted : (succeeded: Bool, msg: String) -> ()) {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url))
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    session.configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    if (err != nil)
    {println("An error occurred during conversion to JSON")}
    println(request.HTTPBody)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data:NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var msg = "No message"

        println(response)
        var respHTTP = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
        if (respHTTP?.statusCode == 200)
        {
            println("Command executed.")
            postCompleted(succeeded: true, msg: "Command Executed.")
        }
        else
        {
            println("Command not executed.")
            postCompleted(succeeded: false, msg: "Command NOT Executed. \(respHTTP?.statusCode)")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

It works perfectly with WiFi connection but for some reason doesn't work with WWAN connection. The request doesn't seem to go out.Please share advices where it went wrong or do I need to configure something at system level?

I am using Xcode 6 and iOS 8 on my iPhone 6, but tested on iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1, got same result.

Addition: error NSError!    domain: "NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709550615 0x00000001700571f0 The completionHandler is called and I've attached the error message. The response is nil

Added:
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0x17027d680 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/carservices/CloseCar, NSUnderlyingError=0x174059890 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1001.)", NSErrorFailingURLKey=xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/carservices/CloseCar}

I found the error code is a timeout code, NSURLErrorTimedOut = -1001
but wonder why it works for WiFi but now for WWAN...

Comment: Have you done any debugging besides noticing that the "request doesn't seem to go out"? Please add more detail - is the `completionHandler` called? What are the values of `error`, `response`, etc?

Comment: -> Aaron,    error NSError! domain: "NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709550615 0x00000001700571f0 The completionHandler is called and I've attached the error message. The response is nil

Comment: For the record, that code is -1 (printed as unsigned).

Comment: -> Kevin Thanks for pointing it out. I am still quite new and exploring the debugger...

Comment: @YaoZhai Can you type `po error` at the `(lldb)` prompt?

Comment: @AndréDaniel Thanks for the suggestion :-) I've reposted my previous debug information for Aaron

Comment: @AaronBrager here it is: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0x17027d680 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/carservices/CloseCar, NSUnderlyingError=0x174059890 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1001.)", NSErrorFailingURLKey=xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/carservices/CloseCar}

Comment: Is there any solution to this question? Its been 2 years.

Comment: @Kevin That code is = -1001 = kCFURLErrorTimedOut

Comment: @Siamaster I was talking about the 18446744073709550615 from the first "addition," which was the only code when I commented.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, me too. That code is -1001 when interpreted as an NSInteger. Which is a known and defined error code in Cocoa framework, kCFURLErrorTimedOut.